# How to get a zero value for some elements in array?

Tags: python, numpy

My output array looks like that below. Then I want to  make all the elements zero which has the value between `(0.75 to 1.06)` `(0,75 > output > 1.06)`.

```
array([2.        , 1.72787724, 1.45575448, 1.18363171, 0.91150895,
       0.63938619, 0.36726343, 0.09514066, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.12235294,
       0.43529412, 0.74823529, 1.06117647, 1.37411765, 1.68705882,
       2.        ])
```

I tried `np.where(0.75 >output >1.06,0,1)`, but it doesn't work:

> ```
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
> ```

Please help me to solve such problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpys built in logical operators to do this.
Try: `np.logical_and(np.where(output > 0.75), np.where(output < 1.06))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.vectorize` to apply function on elements of your array, for example:

```
a = np.array([[-9,-7,-3],[-1,9,3],[1,4,10]])
def func(x):
    if -5<x<5:
        return 0
    else:
        return x
vfunc = np.vectorize(func)
b = vfunc(a)
print(b)
```

output

```
[[-9 -7  0]
 [ 0  9  0]
 [ 0  0 10]]
```